# Azure AD B2C Auth with user Opt in MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm setting up my auth with Azure AD B2C. I want to allow my users to opt into MFA.

I have setup a sign up and sign in user flow, the only option I see is "MFA enable Disable" based on this flow.. Is there a way to enable/disable it based on user not on the flow?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom policy that enables an end user to opt in to (and out from?) MFA.

A good sample to refer to is [the "Sign in with MFA" sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone).

As well as offering both e-mail and phone MFA, you can add a default choice of "None".